# How to weight input for a MultiLayer Perceptron Neural Network Classifier SKLearn Python 3

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, keras, sklearn-pandas

say I have a MLPClassifier from SK-Learn, I have some train data, X_train (n rows), y_train (n rows) and I have a weights vector ( length n)

How would I go about weighting the input to the Classifier assuming that the weights vector sums to 1?

Say:

```py
C = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=hiddenlayers, activation=activation, solver='adam', max_iter=epoch, \
                                  learning_rate_init=0.001, learning_rate = 'adaptive', verbose=False)
```

Defines the classifier.

```
Sp['weights']  <--- pandas.Series
```

Defines the weights to apply to:

```
x_train <--- pandas.DataFrame
```

For fitting to the model by:

```
C.fit(Sp, y_train)
```

Note, that I have already attempted this problem by putting the weights column at the start of Sp, followed by x_train columns and data. I am unsure as to whether this is the solution or not, but anything would be helpful.

Do note, I don't want to move to keras, my program didn't work right using keras, but if there is a solution in keras, do tell that as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly are these weights?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy - these weights represent either: randomly sampled poisson distribution numbers, or following the multiboost method.